# MongoDB. BadValue: security.keyFile is required when authorization is enabled with replica sets

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to configure replica set for `Mongo` in a `Docker` container. I've added replica set to `mongod.conf` file:

```yaml
replication:
    replSetName: "rs0"
```

But during startup I get the next exception:

```
BadValue: security.keyFile is required when authorization is enabled with replica sets
```

I don't want to create any secret keys for now, because it's just a development environment, by that reason, I've just disabled authorization:

```
security:
    authorization: disabled

replication:
    replSetName: "rs0"
```

but it doesn't help and the exception remains. How can I configure `Mongo` in `Docker` with replica set and without authorization?

Answer (score 9):

Specifying the root user and password when running in docker (i.e.  `docker run [...snip...] -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=myuser -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword`) also leads to MongoDB requiring a keyfile.

If you disable authorization and don't specify a keyfile, MongoDB doesn't require a keyfile (as of mongo:6)

Comment: Removing the `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` in the command line solved the error for me. After the mongo server is up, run this command to initialize the root user: ` db.createUser( {
   user: "root",
   pwd: "000000",
   roles: []
 }
 )
`