# security.keyFile error when creating mongdb container with docker-compose file

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

My old docker-compose file config was

```
image: mongo:4.2-bionic
container_name: mongodb1
restart: on-failure
env_file: .env
environment:
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
ports:
  - "$MONGO_PORT:27017"
volumes:
  - data1:/data/db
networks:
  - app_network
command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"]
```

This was working fine. It would create the docker-container and then I would create replica inside docker-container. But then I upgraded the docker image to **mongo:6.0.3** and now every time I try to start the container it throws error:

> BadValue: security.keyFile is required when authorization is enabled
> with replica sets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222424/mongodb-badvalue-security-keyfile-is-required-when-authorization-is-enabled-wi

Answer (score 2):

you need to create your keyfile. A keyfile in MongoDB is used for authentication and to ensure secure communication between members of a replica set or sharded cluster.

You can genereate it like this :

```bash
openssl rand -base64 756 > mongodb-keyfile
```

and then you specify the user ID and the group ID which is often used by mongod (999)

```bash
sudo chown 999:999 mongodb-keyfile
```

and finally you specify it in you docker-compose like this :

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  # Users Mongo
  users_mongo_master:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: users_mongo_master
    ports:
      - 27010:27017
    command: mongod --replSet usersRS --keyFile /etc/mongo/mongodb-keyfile --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
```

and you do the same with your replicas.

Hope that's will help